# How can Angularjs send value of checked checkbox to .php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I want to save the value contained in multiple checkboxes only if they are checked. They would be saved into a MySQL database, using php. Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="panel" ng-controller="checkBoxController"> 
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Cherchez vos contacts" type="text" ng-model="searchText">
    </br>
    <div ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:searchText ">
        <label class="action-checkbox">
            <input id="{{employee.name}}" type="checkbox" value="{{employee.name}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(employee.name) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(employee.name)">
        </label>
        <label for="{{employee.name}}"></label>
            {{employee.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
    </br>
    <span class="selected-item">Destinataires choisis:<span>
    <div ng-repeat="name in selection" class="selected-item">
        {{name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS code.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('checkBoxController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("information.php")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.employees = response.records;
        }); 

    $scope.selection = [];

    // toggle selection for a given employee by name
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(employeeName) {
        var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(employeeName);

        if (idx > -1) {
            $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
        } else {
            $scope.selection.push(employeeName);
        }
    };
});
```

What is the next step? Maybe save in a JSON file and send by HTTP post? I am lost.

Comment: You used `$http.get` to get your employees data from php. You can use `$http.post` to send data to php. So basicly `$http.post("myfile.php", {selection: $scope.selection})` for example.

Comment: you can simply gather formdata and send it to the desired php file which is then doing the insert check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YGQT9/

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I receive noting in my php page.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is have an endpoint that can accept JSON and send your array to it, from a function in your controller.

```
$scope.sendSelection = function() {
    $http.post('your/url.php', { selection: $scope.selection })
        .success(function(data) {
            // Handle success.
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            // Handle error.
        });
}
```

Then have a button to send it in your HTML:

```
<button data-ng-click="sendSelection()">Save Selections</button>
```

Having the PHP file receive and process the JSON array is another thing altogether.

Comment: I have other information to send, so I use  <form name="form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> and I write  <input class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sendSelection()" type="submit" value="Envoyer"/> to submit, but I still can't receive information of checkbox, here is my code php $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
print_r ($data); is it wrong?

Comment: What shows up when you submit the form? The output of `print_r($data);` should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: In the case of your form, you don't need the `ng-click` event on the submit button, since you're not using Angular to submit it. Either that, or you need to include everything from the form in that `sendSelection` function and use `$http.post` and see what the `data` is when it submits.